# Can anyone help me solve this problem?

Tags: fluid-mechanics, fluid

I am a bit confused with this because the channel is not infinite in the z direction. I know that I have to do some things with the Fourier expansion but I'm not sure how. Would be great if anyone could help me do this.

[image]

Comment: Check out boundary layer - many textbooks cover this in detail.

Comment: You will attract subject matter experts if you improve the question title. Every question on the site is "Can anyone help me solve this problem?"